# How to change the font size of the Reminders app?

Tags: macos, font, reminders

Is there a way to increase the font size of the Reminders app? It was easy in Mavericks, by changing a text file inside the app package, but I can't find it anymore on yosemite.

The text is just too small, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the right answer is: it is not possible.