# Can I make Reminders text bigger on Big Sur?

Tags: macos, text, reminders, big-sur

Every year I ask the same question on a new macOS: can I make Reminders text bigger?

I guess it's still impossible on Big Sur too.

Isn't so strange that Reminders app has such small text (smaller than your Safari address bar text)?

thanks

Comment: Your question "isn't it so strange..." Makes this a very subjective question and off topic.  Given that you've already got an [existing question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/155150/119271), it makes this a dupe.  It's still not possible; only Apple can answer why this isn't possible yet and why they haven't implemented this feature.  Have you submitted feedback at https://apple.com/feedback?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I've already submitted feedback at apple.com/feedback. If you read well the post, the question  "isn't it so strange..." is not the main question, just a side question/comment. My existing question you linked is targeting an older macOS, not the more recent one (as specified in the tag). And again, I'm not interested in answering *why* it isn't possible, but *if* is possible on the latest macOS. It looks to me like all your points in your comments are not valid. Can you reconsider them one by one?

Comment: I did submit feedback at Apple, thanks to this question and thanks to the link to Feeback.